# Special and simplest coordinates for a vector field in a neighborhood of a point

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

If $v$ is a smooth vector field in a smooth manifold $M$, there always exist a chart over any $p \in M$ such that, in a neighborhood of $p$, $v$ has coordinates $v^1=1$ and $v^j = 0$, for all $j=2,...,n$ in this chart, or it's just true when $p$ is a regular point of the vector field(i.e.: $p$ is a point such that $v_p \neq 0$)?

Comment: The closure of the set of regular points of a vector field is the support of the vector field. So, for every point $p \in M - \text{supp} v$, there is a neighborhood of $p$ such that $v=0$. I wonder if there is some condition for putting a vector field in such "canonical coordinates" and if depends in which points of $M$ are being considered.

Comment: If the point $p \in M$ is hyperbolic equilibrium (i.e., Jacobi matrix has no eigenvalues with zero real part) then it's impossible to find coordinates such that vector field is straightened in its neighbourhood. This straightening usually can be done only away from singularities.